# OnChange Events for Dynamically rendered User Controls in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a set of User controls shown in a Page (ABC.aspx) in 5 to 6 tabs. Each of the User control has many Textboxes, Drop Downs etc.. I need to detect any user changes on any of the fields in those user controls and do some processing on Parent page (ABC.aspx) on which these user controls reside.

The User Controls are implemented as follows.
There is an XMl file for each of User controls which is read and creates controls accordingly.

The render method in ascx.cs reads this xml file and renders the UI Acordingly for that User Control.

Lets say that sample XMl for a User control is

```
 <uigroup groupname ="Schematic(Logical) Symbol Request">
<uirow>
  <uicontrol displayname="Request Type" datatype="DropDown" isrequired="false" domainname="RequestType" dropdownEventHandler="OnScenarioChange(this)" key="Schematic Scenario" defaultValue="New"></uicontrol>
</uirow>
<uirow>
  <uicontrol displayname="Logical Name" datatype="TextBox" isrequired="false" supportedscenarios="New,Use Existing,Update Existing" key="Schematic Symbol Name"></uicontrol>
  <uicontrol displayname="Similar Symbol" datatype="TextBox" isrequired="false" supportedscenarios="New" key="Similar Schematic Symbol"></uicontrol>
</uirow>
<uirow>
  <uicontrol displayname="Type of Change" datatype="DropDown" isrequired="false" domainname="Type of Schematic Change" supportedscenarios="Update Existing" key="Type of Schematic Change"></uicontrol>
  <uicontrol displayname="Layout Preference" datatype="DropDown" isrequired="false" domainname="Schematic Layout Preference" supportedscenarios="New,Update Existing" key="Schematic Layout Preference"></uicontrol>
</uirow>
<uirow>
  <uicontrol displayname="Justification" datatype="DropDown" isrequired="false" domainname="Schematic Justification" supportedscenarios="Update Existing" key="Schematic Justification"></uicontrol>
  <uicontrol displayname="Logical Directory" datatype="DropDown" isrequired="false"   domainname="ICL Logical Directory" supportedscenarios="New" key="ICL Logical Directory"></uicontrol>
</uirow>
```

Usercontrol.ascx.cs has

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }


    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Render();
    }

    public void Render()
    {
        this.Render(this.XmlPath);
    }
```

and my render function does the following

```
public void Render(string _filePath)
    {


        UITab tab = this.GetDataFromXML(_filePath);
        foreach (UIGroup g in tab.Groups)
        {
            //Add a panel
            Panel groupPanel = this.AddPanel(g);
            foreach (UIRow r in g.Rows)
            {
                Table table = new Table();
                groupPanel.Controls.Add(table);

                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
                table.Rows.Add(tableRow);

                foreach (UIControl c in r.Controls)
                {
                    switch (c.DataType)
                    {
                        case UIDataType.Textbox:
                            this.AddTextBox(groupPanel, c, tableRow);
                            break;
                        case UIDataType.Dropdown:
                            this.AddDropdown(groupPanel, c, tableRow);
                            break;
                        case UIDataType.LabelInfo:
                            this.AddLabelInfo(groupPanel, c,tableRow);
                            break;
                        case UIDataType.Label:
                            this.AddLabel(groupPanel, c,tableRow);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

We are rendering other user controls similar way. we need to find a way to detect user changes on any of these user controls (like a text box changed or dropdown changed etc..) and do process the Parent page.

I am not sure if Delegates and Events might be a good fit and if yes, how would they fit in this architecture are my biggest questions here. Any constructive inputs would really help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, creating a custom event for your UserControl makes a lot of sense.

Here's an example (note: the example shows the basic idea and does not use an XML document as a datasource; nonetheless, the example should be sufficiently instructive that you can apply it to what you've built):

Code for a simple User Control that dynamically injects nested controls:

...in the ascx file:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TabControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="StackOverflowAspNetQuestionAnswers.Controls.TabControl" %>
<asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

...in the code-behind file for the user control:

```
public partial class TabControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler<ControlChangedEventArgs> ControlUpdated;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.AutoPostBack = true;
            textBox.ID = "textBox";

            textBox.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;

            DropDownList dropDown = new DropDownList();
            dropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("Option 1", "Option 1"));
            dropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("Option 2", "Option 2"));
            dropDown.AutoPostBack = true;

            dropDown.TextChanged += dropDown_TextChanged;

            panel.Controls.Add(textBox);
            panel.Controls.Add(dropDown);
        }

        void dropDown_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ControlChangedEventArgs args = new ControlChangedEventArgs();

            args.ControlID = ((DropDownList)sender).ID;
            args.ControlValue = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;

            ControlUpdated(this, args);

            //CODE EDIT:
            UnhookEventHandlers();

        }

        void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ControlChangedEventArgs args = new ControlChangedEventArgs();
            args.ControlID = ((TextBox)sender).ID;
            args.ControlValue = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
            ControlUpdated(this, args);

            //CODE EDIT:
            UnhookEventHandlers();

        }

        public virtual void OnControlUpdated(ControlChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<ControlChangedEventArgs> handler = ControlUpdated;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }

            //CODE EDIT:
            UnhookEventHandlers();

        }

        //CODE EDIT:
        private void UnhookEventHandlers()
        {
            foreach (var c in panel.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>())
            {
                c.TextChanged -= dropDown_TextChanged;
            }

            foreach (var c in panel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                c.TextChanged -= textBox_TextChanged;
            }
        }

    }

    public class ControlChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string ControlID { get; set; }
        public string ControlValue { get; set; }  
    }
```

Here's the code for the parent page that uses this simple tab control:

...in the .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RaisingEventFromUserControl_Question.aspx.cs" Inherits="StackOverflowAspNetQuestionAnswers.RaisingEventFromUserControl_Question" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/TabControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="TabControl" %>


    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="message" runat="server" />
            <uc1:TabControl runat="server" id="TabControl" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

...in the code-behind file of the parent page:

```
 public partial class RaisingEventFromUserControl_Question : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TabControl.ControlUpdated += TabControl_ControlUpdated;
        }

        void TabControl_ControlUpdated(object sender, ControlChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           //EDIT: add code to update some data source to lock the form from other users
            message.Text = String.Format("A child control with an ID of '{0}' was updated. It now has the value of '{1}'.", e.ControlID, e.ControlValue);
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the example, I have a custom event named "ControlUpdated," which I fire anytime there is a change to either the nested TextBox or DropDownList that I dynamically inject into the UserControl at runtime. Also, keep in mind that I set the "AutoPostBack" property for both the TextBox and DropDownList to ensure that the client-side code generated by ASP.Net executes whenever I change the value of the textbox / dropdown.

Also, you can see that for my custom event, I also created a custom EventArgs class so that I could pass along pertinent information from the nested control that is updated (that is, both the ID and the changed value).

Comment: Since the same method is there for every Text box and DropDown we need to add to the User Control, This Event Onchanged gets added to all Text boxes and Dropdowns on the User Controls. So, everytime there's change in there the event will be raised which is kind of overkill. I need to notify the Parent Page once and say do some processing the first time, I know we can use a Static flag to do that, but How about calling an Ajax Method from Javascript? Even this could be a potential Solution I will post a sample code in next comment. Kindly share your views about both and suggest.

Comment: `//On Client Side
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<script>
        var locked = false;
        $("input").change(function() {
          if(!locked){  
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/methodInServer",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (msg) {
                    locked = true;
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
          }
        });
</script>`

Comment: `//On Server Side
[WebMethod]
public static string methodInServer()
{
     //Move the code to Process the page here
     return "Page is locked for other users"
}`

Comment: Thank you for providing more clarification on your requirement. I've edited my answer to account for this. That said, the reason why I provided a server-side code solution is because your question and example code led me to believe that you needed more of a server-side solution than a client-side one.

Comment: If you are looking for a client-side solution, I would recommend moving away from using server-side code for UI construction (in your User Control) and instead move towards UI construction on the client side. There are a number of useful JavaScript libraries (or plugins for existing libraries, e.g. for jQuery) that can provide this facility to you. Lastly, I don't recommend using a "locked" flag which you check in your event handlers. Instead, if you are locking your page after the first change event fires, you should unhook the event handlers so that they don't continually have to execute...

Comment: ...this principle applies as much to a client-side solution as it does to a server-side one.

Comment: I edited my original response to show you an (simplistic) approach to unhooking event handlers. In a production system, I more refined implementation would be necessary.

Comment: I am not inclined to Client or Server side solutions. I just need the best way to do this. That being said, client side will have its advantages as no usage of N/w resources and Bandwidth. And more over, The event handlers don't continually execute because, we are making an Ajax call only if the Page hasn't been locked and that is done by locked flag. I posted a complete Answer for my req in below. Kindly go through it and let me know if you see any glitches. Also, comment on that approach

Comment: In terms of the JavaScript (jQuery) code you've posted, keep in mind that the "change" event handlers, which you're registering via the change function (method) of the jQuery object, do continue to execute. Yes, your "locked" flag prevents the ajax call from being executed more than once, but that doesn't mean that the event handlers aren't being executed.. A refinement to what you have is to unbind (in jQuery) your "change" event handlers once you get a success response from your ajax call. That way, you don't really need that "locked" flag of yours, and you get client-side performance boost.

Comment: As far as the server-side processing of your form goes -- if you are indeed asking about that as well -- I'd need more information about your application. For example, do users login to your app? Does your form implement a "save changes" function, which keeps the user on the form, but can unlock the DB record behind the scenes until the user starts editing the form again? Etc. Something to keep in mind is that hanging a WebMethod off of a code-behind class isn't best practice (create a .asmx instead). Using the old "ASP.Net Web Services" tech isn't recommended either. Consider WebAPI instead.